Are repeated variable names allowed in Python?
Just started learning Python. I've read that you cannot have two variables with the same name in the same scope.
But if I have:
a = 10
print(a)

a = 20
print(a)

a = 30
print(a)

the output is 10, 20, 30. So having the same variable "a" seems to work OK in this example. Can anyone please explain what's going on? Thanks.
EDIT
Still trying to get my head around this. Just so I can see what this restriction looks like, could anyone give a simple example of two variables with the same name in the same scope. Thanks

You're just updating the value of the same variable.  If one were not allowed to change the value of a variable, programming logic would be extremely limited.

" you cannot have two variables with the same name in the same scope.": that is correct: you are using only one variable in your example, reassigning it a new value every time.

Also relevant: Understanding variable types, names and assignment

"I've read" - Where? Did they not have a proper example of what they mean with that?

Your code illustrates what's in a name: the value of a "variable" can "vary".

@trincot There's more: "vary-able"
